# Calculate desired height of scaled down element

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, scale

I'm using CSS `transform: scale(0.6)` to scale down a div. When the element is scaled down, it maintains its aspect ratio. However, in my case, this element needs to always have a height that will reach the bottom of the viewport. This means I need to adjust the height of the element while keeping its width and top position the same.

How do I calculate the height I need to apply so that the element reaches the bottom of the viewport exactly when `transform: scale(x)` is applied?

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('div')[0].style.transform = 'scale(0.44)';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
<div><h1>TEST</h1></div>
```

Comment: Is it an option to use `scaleX(0.44)`? This would keep the height at `100vh`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work in my case because the div is 'squished' and is not proportional.

Comment: Could you provide an example with images illustrated. That might help answering your question

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet works if you replace scale(n) with scaleX(n)

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('div')[0].style.transform = 'scaleX(0.44)';
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Are you looking for a solution to a more general case?

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work in my case because the div is 'squished' and is not proportional

Comment: Ah, that means I have not understood what you want to achieve. If the height is to go to the bottom, what is the width to be and where does the scaling come in?

Comment: The width varies depending on the window width. The scaling is applied when a button is clicked, and it's when the div becomes smaller along with the width and height. The aspect ratio remains the same in this case and in turn, the div height no longer reaches the bottom of the viewport. I need to figure out what new height style to apply to the div so that it reaches the bottom viewport without changing the width or position.